# Show/Hide text after the first paragraph

Tags: jquery

How do i create a Show/Hide script after the first paragraph of a text? The idea goes for `the_content`, where after the first paragraph hide the remaining text with an icon (arrow) and close to reveal the text.

Comment: What you are asking is a pure Javascript/jQuery question and is not specific to WordPress at all. As such, the question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Use both `the_excerpt()` and `the_content()`. Keep `the_content()` hidden, and after `the_exceprt()` add your Icon.
When someone clicks this Icon, toggle between `the_excerpt()` and `the_content()`.